# Bloom: Creating debs. Rosdep can't resolve key

Tags: catkin, rosdep, debian, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create debian packages from my catkin packages with bloom. After the bloom-import-upstream step has finished, the bloom-generate step fails when generating the first package (A) with `Could not resolve rosdep key 'B'`, where B is the name of another package in the same metapackage on which A depends.

`rosdep resolve B` also returns `ERROR: no rosdep rule for 'B'`.

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50197/bloom:-creating-debs.-rosdep-can%27t-resolve-key./) by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bloom resolves all package names (for all build and buildtool dependencies) using rosdep2 which uses the distro.yaml files (among other things) from https://github.com/ros/rosdistro. Until recently that was a problem for first-time releases (or private releases) since they are not in this list.

With the latest bloom version (0.2.13) this is not a problem anymore since all packages from the repository you are about to release will be considered "ok". So please update your "python-bloom" package and retry.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on 2013-01-02**:
OK, thank you. This works now... At least for packages which do not depend on other "private" packages from other repositories. I posted another question regarding this: http://bit.ly/UfbaRz . Perhaps you can help there, too?

**Comment by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on 2013-01-02**:
Another thing: Why do I have to enter my SSH password seven times when accessing the git repo with the new version of bloom? Before, this was two times (Also annoying, but acceptable..)

**Comment by [harrisonmg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35379/harrisonmg/) on 2018-05-22**:
I seem to be having a similar issue - my catkin workspace contains two packages, one of which depends on the other. When I try to use `bloom-generate rosdebian` just to build a .deb for the pacakge, I receive the same `Could not resolve rosdep key` error as in the OP. Python-bloom version 0.6.4-1

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2018-05-22**:
@harrisonmg This is a 5 year old question. Please ask a new question with enough information to reproduce and reference this one.

**Comment by [harrisonmg](https://answers.ros.org/users/35379/harrisonmg/) on 2018-05-23**:
@tfoote Will do, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the answer. But I don't have a groovy.yaml anywhere. Where should it be? And what do you mean with "wait for your pull request to be applied"?

Also, there's nothing in the bloom documentation about having to mess with rosdep somewhere. Is it possible that I'm just missing some setting in one of my package.xml files? On the basis of what does rosdep register the inter-package dependencies?

Just tried with one simple package A which only depends on ros packages. This worked perfectly. But as soon as I transform it to a metapackage B which only contains this package A I get `[git-bloom-generate rosdebian]: Could not resolve rosdep key 'A'`. I saw that it first tries to generate a release for B. Could it be that just the order of generation is wrong? And if yes, can I change it?

---

Originally posted by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) with karma: 73 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-13**:
Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting. This is not a forum. Do not create answers for comments or discussion. Instead edit your original post or use the edit functionality.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-13**:
groovy.yaml is in http://github.com/ros/rosdistro and it's the file used for generating releases. The bloom documentation only mentions that briefly. rosdep is used to resolve dependencies and to decide which dependencies are ros packages and which ones are system dependencies.

**Comment by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on 2012-12-13**:
Sorry for breaking the posting rules. I was not aware of that.

Anyway: I think I now understand what you meant. But I don't want to contribute to ROS, I just want to build debian packages out of my catkin workspace locally. As I said, this works if no metapackage is present. Why?

**Comment by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on 2012-12-13**:
Sorry for breaking the posting rules. I was not aware of that.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-13**:
As I said, in that case you need to create fake-rosdep rules. Have a look at the rosdep documentation on how to contribute rules. You can basically use your own rosdep database. Add your packages in the meta package there and the debian build should work.

**Comment by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on 2012-12-14**:
Ok, now I see what you meant. How would I do that? As far as I understand the only way is to upload some yaml file to a remote server and enter the adress in the sources list of rosdep. Specifying a local file doesn't work, already tried that. Isn't there another way?

**Comment by [danielm0hr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3764/danielm0hr/) on 2012-12-14**:
Ok, now I see what you meant. How would I do that? As far as I understand the only way is to upload some yaml file to a remote server and enter the adress in the sources list of rosdep. Specifying a local file doesn't work, already tried that.